# How to parse date time from json?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Action Method like this

```
public ActionResult TodayJson()
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            return Json(today,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

that returns me the the following value

```
"\/Date(1369332000000)\/"
```

How can I parse it in actual date time by the jquery or java script. Format should be like this dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this in your javascript (while `jsonDate = "\/Date(1369332000000)\/"`):

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
var formattedDate = date.format("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Source: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date/2316066#2316066)

Comment: Note that solution wouldn't be time zone safe.

Comment: @MikeChristensen - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066/1203115 - look at the second comment (+35), it will work if timezone offset is specified.

Comment: now it gives "24-00-2013". it's not the actual value

Comment: Yes, however your date format is `"dd-mm-yyyy"`.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor - You probably want `dd-MM-yyyy`, lower case `mm` is minute, not month.

Comment: Sorry had a mistake in the date.format string.